# Lower Bound on $E[\frac{1}{X}]$ for positive symmetric distribution

Tags: probability, expectation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X$ be positive random variable and its distribution is symmetric about its mean value $m$. Then
$$ E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] \geq \frac{1}{m} + \frac{\sigma^2}{m^3},
$$
where $\sigma^2$ is variance of $X$. I can just prove that $$ E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right] \geq \frac{1}{m},
$$
using Jensen, but somehow can't incorporate symmetry and get also the second term.